# How to Measure the Bandwidth Utilization of a Link

Tags: sockets

I have written a Socket program which uses read and write command to send and receive data .
I am running it on two server .Both Servers are connected with a 10 Gbps link .
Now How I can measure that How much Bandwidth ,Link Utilization is going one by my program .

Comment: Try "Vnstat". It will provide bandwidth utilization real time.

Answer (score 0):

Several methods are possible, but here is one: run `tcpdump` on either of the servers and have it measure traffic to and from the port on the local host. Write this to a large dump file and use something like `tcpstat` to extract the total length. Another one: have your socket program itself calculate the amount of data sent and received at the socket level, and work out the IP and ethernet or other link layer overhead to get the amount of data on the line. Divide by time to get bandwidth utilization.

Comment: Suppose I Generated 10000 bytes in 10 s .So Generation Speed is 1000 bytes/s .

Comment: Yes, that is the speed on the TCP level, but as I said, you need to add IP and Ethernet overhead. Your 10000 bytes are possibly sent in 6 or 7 packets, each having something like 24 bytes for the IP header plus 24 bytes for the Ethernet frame. So the actual bandwidth is closer to 10300 bytes in 10 s, is 1030 bytes/s. `tcpdump` will take all these extra bytes into account.